# I want to make a window dynamically move the elements. How exactly would I do that?

Tags: c++

I currently have this, but it's not working.

How would I do that?

By dynamic, I mean like [this](http://i.imgur.com/ijdQqQa.gifv)

```
int X = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE);
int Y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZE);

// Window
#define WBARSIZE int(X + 128 / BARS)
#define WWIDTH (BARS * WBARSIZE)
#define WHEIGHT Y + 128 / 6.35
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: I want to make it dynamically resize, where it fits the window, no matter what size the window is

Comment: That should be in the question itself, not a comment.

Comment: 3 seconds in Google showed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4985/Easy-dialog-control-resizer)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on which library you use for window management. Is it Qt? Win32? Something else?

The general idea of what you should do is anchor the widgets to different places, and let them move relative to their anchors.

Comment: It's WIn32. 

"The general idea of what you should do is anchor the widgets to different places, and let them move relative to their anchors."

How?

Comment: @will0945 I've no experience with win32 so your guess is as good as mine. Google a bit, or wait for a more in-depth answer from someone else.

Comment: @will0945 When you create the widget, if it is in the lower right of the window record 1) how tall and wide the window is 2) how far the right side of the widget is from the right side of the window and 3) how far the bottom of the widget is from the bottom of the window.  Then when you get a WM_SIZE message 1) calc the new height versus the original height % 2) calc the new width versus the original width % 3) move the widget so the bottom is "height percentage * original bottom distance" from the bottom edge and the right is "width percentage * original right distance" from the right edge.